# In CGridView and CButtonColumn issue

Tags: php, yii

I have the following array in a CGridView:

```
array(
    'header' => Yii::t('dataTable', 'Actions'),
    'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
    'template' => '{action}',
    'buttons' => array(
        'action' => array(
            'label' => '$data["action"]["action"]',
            'url' => function($data) use($paramsURI) {
                $paramsURI['action'] = $data['action']['action'];
                $paramsURI['id'] = $data['id'];
                return Yii::app()->createUrl(
                     "admin/report/transactions", $paramsURI
                );
            }
        )
    )
)
```

I need to use the `$data` on button label, but in `'label' => '$data["action"]["action"]'`, `$data` is undefined, so I try to use a closure how in 'action', but the error is `'htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given '`.

Any ideia how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use CButtonColumn, create simple column with `'type'=>'raw'` and show in this field anything you want.

Comment: Alex this work in my case. But if someone need to use the buttons funcionalities, a better approach is follow the nazim approach.

Comment: If you have 10 different labels you don't want to create 10 buttons, do you? :)

Answer (score 2):

I do not think labels support eval expressions. You could use the visible option to hide and show data sensitive labels like this instead. In the below case "Action 1" is shown if $data['action']['action'] =="Action 1" and Action 2 appropriately. Observe 'template' and 'visible' keys here.

```
array(
    'header' => Yii::t('dataTable', 'Actions'),
    'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
    'template' => '{action1 action2}',
    'buttons' => array(
        'action1' => array(
            'label' => 'Action 1',
            'visible' => '$data["action"]["action"]=="Action 1"',
            'url' => function($data) use($paramsURI) {
                $paramsURI['action'] = $data['action']['action'];
                $paramsURI['id'] = $data['id'];
                return Yii::app()->createUrl(
                     "admin/report/transactions", $paramsURI
                );
            }
        ),
        'action2' => array(
            'label' => 'Action 2',
            'visible' => '$data["action"]["action"]=="Action 2"',
            'url' => function($data) use($paramsURI) {
                $paramsURI['action'] = $data['action']['action'];
                $paramsURI['id'] = $data['id'];
                return Yii::app()->createUrl(
                     "admin/report/transactions", $paramsURI
                );
            }
        )
    )
```

)

Comment: nazim this is a good approach, but the result is not the expected, you can see here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/98574/774568/LAMiBLacN7gfsia/example.png

Comment: @Maykonn you need to ensure that the keys in the template 'action1' and 'action2' match the keys in the 'buttons' array. You might want to try with a **static** url. I am not familiar with the approach you are using to generate your urls. 

I would use something like 'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("admin/report/transactions",array("action"=>$data["action"]["action"],"id"=>$data["id"]))', instead.

Comment: I use a closure because `Yii::app()->createUrl()` give an error on eval(), some relared with & and = in the URL. And I need the GET params from REQUEST_URI when I click in a button from rows. The $paramsURI is a parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) and an explode in each item from url. Just work. Thanks!

Comment: Fair enough. But I don't think $data gets evaluated outside the quotes. Your url value starting with function($data) are not in quotes. Just a hunch :)

Comment: Yes, but just when passed by param to closure `function($data)`.